# How to convert JSONArray to List in Grails?

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I have a list and JSONArray in Grails as below:

```
def siteList = []    

def siteURLArray = new JSONArray()
siteURLArray.put(foo)
```

How to convert JSONArray to list? below is not working

```
siteList = siteURLArray as List
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to convert. A `JSONArray` is already a list. It implements the `java.util.List` interface.

See [**javadoc**](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/json/JSONArray.html)